# Google Analytics 4 API dateHour is not working?

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

It looks like dateHour in GA4 API is not working. It always returns no rows. What happens to this? I am using the GA4 query explorer.

Answer (score 0):

`dateHour` is working. Here's an example response:[image: dateHourResponse]

Do other dimensions like `date` and `eventName` work on your property?

Comment: When I combined it with totalUsers, it returns no rows.